# Запятая перед союзом "как"

Tags: пунктуация

Народ, помогите, пожалуйста! Где в этом предложении нужно ставить запятые и почему?

Так, распад СССР(,) как единого социального субъекта(,) привел к ряду вызовов и угроз в вопросах безопасности, включая проблемы в сфере энергетики России и государств СНГ.

Comment: @Alenka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приложение с союзом "как", употребляемым в значении "в качестве", запятыми не выделяется, так что и в Вашем предложении запятая не нужна

Comment: Т.е. обе запятые не нужны? Я правильно поняла?

Comment: Я написал, что приложение запятыми не выделяется, значит, обе запятые не нужны. Запятая ставится только после слова "так", ибо это вводное слово